# javascript function working in firefox but not in google chrome

Tags: javascript, hide, show-hide

I have made one simple functionality and it is working in fire fox perfectly but not in google chrome . It is giving problem with hide() function and showing loading image and Rest of function is working ok .

```
function setPrivacyToCustom(){
    $("form#email_contacts_form #gmail_import_btn").unbind();
    $("form#email_contacts_form #gmail_import_btn").click(function()
            {
                var current_album_id = $(this).siblings('input#selected_album_id').val();
                $(this).hide();
                var loading_img = addLoadingImage( $(this), "before", 'loading_medium_purple.gif',61, 32 );
                var usersList = "";
                var total = $("input[name='emails[]']:checked:enabled").length;
                $("input[name='emails[]']:checked:enabled").each(function(index) 
                {
                    if (index === total - 1) 
                    {
                        // this is the last one
                        usersList += $(this).attr('rel');
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        usersList += $(this).attr('rel')+",";
                    }   
                });
                var thisss = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url : "/" + PROJECT_NAME + "profile/set-custom-privacy-and-viewers-for-album",
                    method : "POST",
                    data :{"custom_viewer" : usersList, "album_id":current_album_id},
                    type : "post",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(jsonData)
                    {                    
                        if(jsonData == 1)
                        {
                            $("span#"+loading_img).remove();
                            $('div#gmail_popup').bPopup().close();
                            $("span#"+loading_img).remove();
                            $(thisss).fadeIn();
                            $(".alert-box").remove();
                            $(".alert-box1").remove();
                            $(".alert-box2").remove();
                            showDefaultMsg( " Your setting changes have been saved.", 1 );

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Some error has occured.Please select custom user again.");
                        }

                    }

                });

            });
}
```

**The above is code I have written and**

```
 $(this).hide();
  var loading_img = addLoadingImage( $(this), "before", 'loading_medium_purple.gif',61, 32 );
```

**these two lines are not working where button hides and loading image appears .**

The function to show loading image is as follows

```
function addLoadingImage(elem, position, image_name, width, height)
{
    image_name = typeof image_name !== 'undefined' ? image_name : "loading_small_purple.gif";
    width = typeof width !== 'undefined' ? width : "0";
    height = typeof height !== 'undefined' ? height : "0";

    var unique_num = new Date().getTime();
    var obj = "<span class = 'loading' id = '"+unique_num+"' ><table><tr><td style = 'width:"+width+"px; height:"+height+"px'><img src = '/" + PROJECT_NAME + "public/images/" + image_name + "' alt = 'Wait...' /></td></tr></table></span>";
    elem.siblings("span.loading").remove();
    if( position == "before" )
    {
        $(obj).insertBefore( elem );
    }
    else if( position == "after" )
    {
        $(obj).insertAfter( elem );
    }
    return unique_num;
}
```

the above code is working in fire fox perfectly but not in google chrome :(

Comment: check the console for errors. That may help you to track where your code is breaking.

Comment: Its working perfectly ok when i write same code in console @AshishKumar

Comment: dont write anything, just check for the errors on load. I believe there should be something `null` or `undefined` issue with any variable as you are saying that running that code from console is working fine.

Comment: there must be one or more object not supported by Chrome then as a possibility.

Comment: create and share a fiddle containing your HTML and js function.

Comment: @Sunny code is huge and there are several files that I am using so can't create it on fiddle.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal I am not getting any error just hide function is not working as i mention in my question .

Comment: there must be some error showing in console. Even if in case it's not showing, you can navigate through each line of code in execution in console. Use breakpoints. Find your code block under "Sources" Tab and put breakpoints and then try to reload the page.

Comment: that was happening because of  async: false . now its working Fine. thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening because of async:false . because when i made my ajax call asynchronous false it halted the other events that were to be occur . I should have known the right implementation of asyn:false before writing such a code . thanks @sunny , @ashish kumar for help .